# GraphQL-NetCore. Override params in where clause

Tags: .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am trying to override parameters passed in `where` clause which is then used to build the expression tree.

In our response to client property `userId` is encrypted and passed as `encryptedUserId`, in all objects where this property is present.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allEmployees": {
        "totalCount": 51,
        "items": [
            {
                "firstName": "Kristi",
                "encryptedUserId": "8f9279f2c81f22d4a088909c5035dd0f"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Samantha",
                "encryptedUserId": "df194ab35837a323"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Ernesto",
                "encryptedUserId": "8927b824450aaad73222166c1e34cb5b"
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

The issue we are facing comes to queries where client wants to filtrate data based on this `userId`. So lets assume we want to filtrate the above list by `encryptedUserId`, here is what the client normally will do:

```
query{
  allEmployees (
    where: {
        encryptedUserId: {
            eq: "8f9279f2c81f22d4a088909c5035dd0f"
        }
    }
  ){
    totalCount
    items{
        firstName
        encryptedUserId
    }
  }
}
```

As we are using IQueryable it's getting translated straight to `.Where(_s0 => _s0.EncryptedUserId == __p_1)`, how we can intercept this and override the build expression and create a valid expression for sql?

```
var decryptedUserId = Decrypt(request.EncryptedUserId);
expression.Where(_s0 => decryptedUserId == __p_1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who could might need an solution, posting my workaround.

I ended up extending the Hot Chocolate [IHttpRequestInterceptor](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/server/interceptors), checking if the incoming query contains filtering by `encryptedUserId` and overriding the query.

```
public override ValueTask OnCreateAsync(HttpContext context,
    IRequestExecutor requestExecutor, IQueryRequestBuilder requestBuilder,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var query = requestBuilder.Create();
    var queryString = query.Query!.ToString();

    if (!queryString.Contains(WhereKey) || !queryString.Contains(EncryptedUserIdKey))
        return base.OnCreateAsync(context, requestExecutor, requestBuilder, cancellationToken);

    var builder = QueryBuilder(queryString, query.VariableValues);

    requestBuilder.SetQuery(builder.query);
    requestBuilder.SetVariableValues(builder.variables);

    return base.OnCreateAsync(context, requestExecutor, requestBuilder,
        cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood completely what needs to be done.
From what I've understood you need to intercept that query and modify the where clause.
I don't have any place to test this scenario, but I found this article on .net EF core example, that might help. https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/07/18/net-ef-core-interceptors-to-modify-database-commands/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, already tried this one but it fails prior reaching the db context as it tries first to validate the generated Expression tree.